# set default drop down value on php generated form

Tags: php, html, html-select

I generated a drop down menu with the code below. How can I set the field to the GET variable after submit is clicked?

```
<select>

<?php
    $sql="SELECT c FROM problems WHERE b='$id'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    $options=""; 

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $id=$row["c"]; 
    $c=$row["c"]; 
    $options.="<option value=\"$id\">".$c; 
    } 
?>
        <option value=''>C <?=$options?>  </option>     
</select>
```

Comment: or is there just a better way to create a drop down from a mysql table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select>

<?php
    $sql="SELECT c FROM problems WHERE b='$id'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    $options=""; 

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $id=$row["c"]; 
    $c=$row["c"]; 
    if($_GET['var'] == $id)
      echo '<option selected="selected" value=\"$id\">' . $c . '</option>';
    else
       echo '<option value=\"$id\">' . $c . '</option>'; 
    } 
?>

</select>
```

Basic idea is compare value GET data with database data and using if else condition add selected="selected" if condition matched. I am directly printing string as they will not be getting use later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you want to know. To have an option selected by default, use the `selected="selected"` attribute on that option.

If you want to know how to get the submitted value in PHP, you need to assign the `name` attribute to the `<select>` tag. In general, however, you've got the idea right.

Comment: when you submit a textbox with GET you see the inputted info in the URL and in the textbox if you set the value to <?php $_GET['var']; ?> im trying to get this effect with a dropdown.  however, my dropdown is unorthodox.  it's irregular because it takes values from a table.  i have 2 concerns.  am i generating the drop down most efficiently and how can i get that value=GET effect from the textbox